# convert aspx textbox value to html formatted text

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, email

In my application for sending an Inquiry mail, i have a text box for enter address..
if i type address in the textbox like below

```
33A, sector -8,   /*Pressed enter Key*/
Sanpada,         /*Pressed enter Key*/
Navi mumbai.
```

it should be display in the mail as like

```
33A, sector -8, 
Sanpada,
Navi mumbai.
```

but it is displaying like

```
33A, sector -8, Sanpada,Navi mumbai.
```

my code for sending mail is

```
string content = "";
string sub = "";
content = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("../mail/MasterJnenquiry.html"));
content = content.Replace("##CustomerCompanyName##", txtCompanyName.Text);
content = content.Replace("##CompanyName##", txtCompanyName.Text);
content = content.Replace("##ContactName##", txtContactname.Text);
content = content.Replace("##ContactNo##", txtContactNo.Text);
content = content.Replace("##EmailId##", txtemailid.Text);
content = content.Replace("##EnquiryMessage##", txtenqmess.Text);
content = content.Replace("##Designation##", txtdesignation.Text);
content = content.Replace("##Address##", txtadress.Text);
content = content.Replace("##ProductDetails##", txtProductdetails.Text);
sub = "お客様のお問い合わせ≪インドの窓口≫";
```

how to display textbox text in the mail in html format??

Comment: I believe you need to replace the CRLF characters with <br>?

Answer (score 0):

i did the following to solve my problem..

```
   string content = "";
            string sub = "";
            content = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("../mail/MasterJnenquiry.html"));
            content = content.Replace("##CustomerCompanyName##", txtCompanyName.Text);
            content = content.Replace("##CompanyName##", txtCompanyName.Text);
            content = content.Replace("##ContactName##", txtContactname.Text);
            content = content.Replace("##ContactNo##", txtContactNo.Text);
            content = content.Replace("##EmailId##", txtemailid.Text);
            content = content.Replace("##EnquiryMessage##", txtenqmess.Text);
            content = content.Replace("##Designation##", txtdesignation.Text);
            string addr = Server.HtmlEncode(txtadress.Text);             
            addr = addr.Replace("\n", "<br/>");
            content = content.Replace("##Address##", addr);
            content = content.Replace("##ProductDetails##", txtProductdetails.Text);
            sub = "お客様のお問い合わせ≪インドの窓口≫";
```

The change in the code is

```
string addr = Server.HtmlEncode(txtadress.Text);             
            addr = addr.Replace("\n", "<br/>");
            content = content.Replace("##Address##", addr);
```